# Consulta tabla en dos columnas pero una en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla que posee dentro de sus columnas:
periodo (2017-10, 2017-11, etc.)
monto_caja (valores)
facturado (posee "si" y "no").
Necesito hacer una tabla con 4 columnas: EL periodo, el monto no facturado por periodo, el monto facturado por periodo, y la suma de ambos.
Actualmente tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT periodo AS PERIODO, 
(select  sum(capsur_vtr.monto_caja) AS 'NO FACTURADO' from capsur_vtr  
WHERE periodo not like '%proforma%' and facturado = 'SI'
) AS FACTURADO, 
(select 
sum(capsur_vtr.monto_caja) AS 'NO FACTURADO' from capsur_vtr
WHERE periodo not like '%proforma%' and facturado = 'NO'
) AS NO_FACTURADO, 
sum(capsur_vtr.monto_caja) AS TOTAL FROM capsur_vtr
where periodo not like '%proforma%'
group by periodo
order by periodo
```

La cual me arroja esto:

[image: consulta]

Obviamente me esta tomando el total dentro de cada celda de las columnas de facturado y no facturado (la suma de las celdas de ambas columnas en una fila es igual al acumulado del total)
¿como hago para que en cada celda el valor sea la suma sólo del período?

Gracias por su ayuda.
Rodrigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, puedes probar a sumar en base a condición, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
SELECT periodo AS PERIODO,
SUM(IF (c.facturado = "SI",c.monto_caja,0)) AS FACTURADO,
SUM(IF (c.facturado = "NO",c.monto_caja,0)) AS NO-FACTURADO,
SUM(c.monto_caja) AS TOTAL
FROM capsur_vtr c
WHERE c.periodo NOT LIKE '%proforma%'
GROUP BY c.periodo ORDER BY c.periodo
```

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!